# Java method return type acceptable for method argument [...]

Tags: java

Following method signature:

```
public void doSomeStuff(Foo ... names){

}
```

now assume that I have a `List<String> names` which I want to convert to `Foo`s which I then can pass into `doSomeStuff()`.

As it would be pretty convenient to have a method create all the `Foo`s, I thought about implementing a method as following:

```
public Foo[] createFoos(List<String> names){
    Foo[] foos = new Foo[names.size()];
    //create all the Foo's and pass them into array
    return foos;
}
```

in the end I would like to have this kind of code (I have a few `Foo`s from other sources available or they do require special treatment):

```
doSomeStuff(foo1, foo2, createFoos(names));
```

**So the question is, is it possible to implement a method (`createFoos()`) which returns an object that is accepted by a method with the `Foo ... names` signature, and if so, how would one go about it?**

---

<sub>I am sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find anything regarding this topic</sub>

EDIT:

As I just realized, the requirements are a bit different. Sorry about the confusion. Updated the method call.

The crucial part is that I need to pass in a few `Foo`s which are from other sources/not created by `createFoos()` method as well

Comment: "Sadly, Foo[] is not an return type which is accepted by Foo ... names" [Yes it is](https://ideone.com/cGQARh)

Comment: "Sadly, Foo[] is not an return type which is accepted by Foo ... names": that is not correct. Arrays are valid arguments for var-arg parameters. Did you actually try it?

Comment: I updated the requirements. I forgot a very crucial part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move those extra `foo1` and `foo2` into the `createFoo`s method

```
public Foo[] createFoos(List<String> names, Foo... extraFoos){
    Foo[] foos = new Foo[names.size() + extraFoos.length];
    //create all the Foo's and pass them into array
    return foos;
}
```

Call it like so

```
doSomeStuff(createFoos(names, foo1, foo2));
```

Alternatively, return a list and then append to it, then finally turn it into an array.

```
public List<Foo> createFoos(List<String> names){
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
    //create all the Foo's and pass them into array
    return foos;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Foo> foos = createFoos(names);
foos.add(foo1);
foos.add(foo2);
doSomeStuff(foos.toArray(new Foo[0]));
```

Comment: I managed to completely clean up my code (still not best, but much better) with the help of this answer. In the end I created another method which would simply convert my existing `Foo`s into a `List<Foo>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Also change the return type of the createFoos() method to List and convert the array into List by using Arrays class method Arrays.asList()

```
public List<string> createFoos(List<String> names){
    Foo[] foos = new Foo[names.size()];
    //convert Array into List 
   List<String> foosList = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(foos);
    return foosList;
}
```